# How can I Allocate a dynamic memory slot for a structure inside a function, Which can be accessed from anywhere in the program

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int insert(struct node *temp, char *input_string, int str_len) {
    char ch = *input_string;
    int copied=str_len;
    int i;
    temp =(struct node *) temp->child_nodes[ch];
    if (temp->data[0] == "NULL") { //when the node is empty and has no data in its data[]
        for (i = 0; i < str_len; i++) {
            temp->data[i] = *input_string;//copy the character into the array
            input_string++;//increment the pointer to get next character to be inserted
        }//for closed
        return 1; //function job completed
    }//if closed
    else {
        i = 0;
        while (str_len - copied) {
            if (temp->data[i] == ch) {//till the characters are same to be inserted.
                copied++;
                i++;
                 input_string++;
                 ch = *input_string;
                continue;
            }
            else //when the data to be inserted is not same.
            {
                //initialise a node1 and node2 memory code here.
                temp->no_of_child_nodes += 2;
                temp->child_nodes[temp->data[i]] = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                temp->child_nodes[ch] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                while (temp->data[i] != "NULL") {//check for the parent node data to reach NULL
                    node1->data[i] = temp->data[i];//copy data
                    i++;//increment I       
                }
                while (str_len - copied) {
                    node2->data[i] = ch;
                    input_string++;
                    ch++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Function Insert, i face a situation where I need to Add two structure nodes inside a Function. As the memory allocated will be freed upon exiting Function, How can I fix this?

Comment: unclear, please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to access a dynamically allocated structure everywhere, you're going to need have access to its location to be able to reference it anywhere, and for this we use pointers. Let me show you an example.

Let's say you have a `Point` data type to represent a point in three-dimensional space.

```
typedef struct point_t {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} *Point;
```

Now you can create a "builder" function -not unlike a constructor in C++, although not quite- where you set its initial values and return its pointer. This is how you're allocating the structure dynamically and preserving a pointer to it so that you can continue to use it in other parts of your program.

```
Point createPoint(double a, double b, double c) {
    Point newPoint = malloc(sizeof(struct point_t));

    if (newPoint == NULL) { /* Handle failure here... */ }

    SetPoint(&newPoint,a,b,c);

    return newPoint;
}
```

And then you would just define `SetPoint` like this:

```
void SetPoint(Point* p, double a, double b, double c) {
    if (p == NULL) { return; }

    *p->x = a;
    *p->y = b;
    *p->z = c;
}
```

To actually use the structure, you're going to have to do two things. First, you're going to have to construct the structure, then you'll have to pass it to the other function that needs it. You've already seen this at work, in the `SetPoint` function above.

Notice that `Point* p` declares a *double pointer* to a structure of type `struct point_t`. We need one layer of indirection to work with the pointer itself and then one additional layer of indirection so that we can pass the pointer by reference and modify its contents in the function. If we passed in a regular `Point` handle, the pass by value mechanism would discard the effects of the functions.

So with this hypothetical data structure, your `main` function might use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    Point origin = createPoint(0,0,0);
    PrintPoint(origin);

    Point p1 = createPoint(1,-1,5);
    PrintPoint(p1);

    printf("Distance between p1 and the origin: %lf\n", DistanceBetween(p1,origin));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You might define `Print Point` like this:

```
void PrintPoint(Point p) {
    if (p == NULL) { return; }

    printf("(%lf,%lf,%lf)\n", p->x, p->y, p->z);
}
```

Likewise, you can define the `DistanceBetween` function like this: (Remember that the distance between any two points in three-dimensional Euclidean space is basically the Pythagorean Theorem but with an extra dimension.

```
double DistanceBetween(Point a, Point b) {
    return sqrt(pow((b->x - a->x),2) + pow((b->y - a->y),2) + pow((b->z - a->z),2));
}
```

---

For some general pointers, remember to stay vigilant about `NULL` pointers. Not only can they cause a segmentation fault or give you garbage results -sometimes this is even worse imo- but it can also lead to code vulnerabilities, like the "double free" exploit in zlib years ago. There was another one recently but I didn't read the exploit summary.

If you want to play it safe with with double free's, you can use the method Professor Reese wrote about in "Understanding and Using C Pointers." If we apply it to the hypothetical `Point` structure from above, it looks like this:

```
void SafeFree(Point* pointHandle) {
    if (*pointHandle == NULL) { return; }

    free(*pointHandle);
    *pointHandle = NULL;
}
```

Notice that we're passing in the pointer we want to free by reference (so you'd have to free it like this: `free(&origin)`, for example. This is so that we can set it to `NULL` once we've free'd it. This way, if you were to call free on the same memory location, **even if it was being referenced by a different pointer**, this `NULL` check would save you from double-freeing memory.

Anyways, just an added precaution, I hope all this helps, let me know if you have any more questions.